# Use toggle button to set the visibility of a curve

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, visual-studio-code, jupyter

Use three toggle buttons to set curve1-3 be display/not display.
After toggle button is pressed, the curve does not be invisible, is there any missing?

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import ipywidgets as widgets
from IPython.display import display

# Create x values
x = np.linspace(0, 2*np.pi, 100)

# Create y values for each curve
y1 = x

# Create the initial plot with all curves visible
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
line1, = ax.plot(x, y1, label='y = x')
ax.legend()

# Create toggle buttons control
button1 = widgets.ToggleButton(value=True, description='y = x')

# Define callback function to update line visibility
def update_line_visibility(change):
    line1.set_visible(button1.value)
    plt.draw()

# Bind toggle buttons control and callback function
button1.observe(update_line_visibility, 'value')

# Display toggle buttons control
display(button1)

# Show the plot
plt.show()
```

#### Package Versions

```
python kernel = 3.11.0,
related package version are

ipykernel                6.20.2\
ipympl                   0.9.3\
ipython                  8.8.0\
ipython-genutils         0.2.0\
ipywidgets               7.6.3\
jupyter                  1.0.0\
jupyter_client           7.4.9\
jupyter-console          6.6.3\
jupyter_core             5.1.5\
jupyter-events           0.6.3\
jupyter_packaging        0.12.3\
jupyter_server           2.5.0\
jupyter_server_fileid    0.9.0\
jupyter-server-proxy     3.2.2\
jupyter_server_terminals 0.4.4\
jupyter_server_ydoc      0.8.0\
jupyter-ydoc             0.2.4\
jupyterlab               3.6.3\
jupyterlab-pygments      0.2.2\
jupyterlab_server        2.22.1\
jupyterlab-vpython       3.1.4\
jupyterlab-widgets       3.0.5\
matplotlib               3.6.3\
matplotlib-inline        0.1.6\
python-dateutil          2.8.2\
python-json-logger       2.0.7\
QtPy                     2.3.1\
vpython                  7.6.4\
websocket-client         1.5.1\
wheel                    0.40.0\
widgetsnbextension       3.5.2
```

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).